# Correct cyclic garbage collection in extension modules

Tags: python, c, garbage-collection, python-c-api, python-extensions

Two sections of Python 2.7's documentation mentioned adding *cyclic garbage collection* (CGC) support for container objects defined in extension modules.

The [Python/C API Reference Manual](http://docs.python.org/c-api/gcsupport.html?highlight=pyobject_gc_newvar) gives two rules, i.e.,

> 1. The memory for the object must be allocated using `PyObject_GC_New()` or `PyObject_GC_NewVar()`.
> 2. Once all the fields which may contain references to other containers are initialized, it must call `PyObject_GC_Track()`.

Whereas in [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html?highlight=noddy_traverse#supporting-cyclic-garbage-collection), for the `Noddy` example, it seems that adding the `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC` flag and filling `tp_traverse` and `tp_clear` slots would be sufficient to enable CGC support. And the two rules above are *not* practiced at all.

When I modified the `Noddy` example to actually follow the rules of `PyObject_GC_New()`/`PyObject_GC_Del()` and `PyObject_Track()`/`PyObject_GC_UnTrack()`, it surprisingly raised assertion error saying,

> Modules/gcmodule.c:348: visit_decref: Assertion "gc->gc.gc_refs != 0" failed. refcount was too small

What is the correct and safe way to implement CGC? What would be a *neat* example of a container object with CGC support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under most normal circumstances you shouldn't need to do do the tracking/untracking yourself. This is described in the documentation, however it isn't made specifically clear. In the case of the [`Noddy` example](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html) you definitely don't.

The short version is that a TypeObject contains two function pointers: `tp_alloc` and `tp_free`. By default `tp_alloc` calls all the right functions on creation of a class (if `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC` is set) and `tp_free` untracks the class on destruction.

The [Noddy documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#supporting-cyclic-garbage-collection) (at the end of the section):

> That’s pretty much it. If we had written custom `tp_alloc` or `tp_free` slots, we’d need to modify them for cyclic-garbage collection. Most extensions will use the versions automatically provided.

Unfortunately, the one place that doesn't make it clear that you don't need to do this yourself is the [Supporting Cyclic Garbage Collection documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/gcsupport.html).

---

**Detail:**

Noddy's are allocated using a function called `Noddy_new` put in the `tp_new` slots of the `TypeObject`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_new), the main thing the "new" function should do is call the [`tp_alloc` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_alloc). You typically don't write `tp_alloc` yourself, and it just defaults to `PyType_GenericAlloc()`.

Looking at [`PyType_GenericAlloc()` in the Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4f15bc3d0bdba6474d73ee0dbd2ccd2c34d6bd5/Objects/typeobject.c#L929) shows a number of sections where it changes based on `PyType_IS_GC(type)`. First it calls `_PyObject_GC_Malloc` instead of `PyObject_Malloc`, and second it calls `_PyObject_GC_TRACK(obj)`. [Note that all that `PyObject_New` really does is call `PyObject_Malloc` and then `tp_init`.]

Similarly, on deallocation you call the [`tp_free` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_free), which is automatically set to [`PyObject_GC_Del`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Modules/gcmodule.c#L1787) for classes with `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC`. `PyObject_GC_Del` includes code that does the same as `PyObject_GC_UnTrack` so a call to untrack is unnecessary.

Comment: So are you saying that the Noddy example does not need to call PyObject_GC_UnTrack in Noddy_dealloc? If that is the case, is the Noddy example wrong?

Comment: @VictorLiu It's been a while since I wrote this answer so it's a little vague in my mind. I'm fairly sure the bit about allocation is right and that `GC_Malloc` and `GC_Track` are automatically called appropriately. At the point I wrote the answer the default `tp_free` automatically untracked it. That behaviour has changed and it'll issue a warning in debug mode. So you should call `PyObject_GC_UnTrack` in `Noddy_dealloc` (and thus the `Noddy` example is right). I suspect the last paragraph of this answer wasn't good advice in hindsight - you get away with it, but really you should call it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not experienced enough in the C API myself to give you any advice, but there are plenty of *examples* in the Python container implementations themselves.

Personally, I'd start with the tuple implementation first, since it's immutable: [Objects/tupleobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/tupleobject.c). Then move on to the `dict`, `list` and `set` implementations for further notes on mutable containers:

- [Objects/dictobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c)
- [Objects/listobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c)
- [Objects/setobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/setobject.c)

I can't help but notice that there are calls to `PyObject_GC_New()`, `PyObject_GC_NewVar()` and `PyObject_GC_Track()` throughout, as well as having `Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC` set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am investigating the possibility that some versions of the `PyObject_GC_New()` API cannot correctly handle subtypes, which is the cause of the AssertionError.